# UIToolbar categories drawRect: won't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uitoolbar, categories

I've tried the following:

```
@implementation UIToolbar (Image)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigationBar.png"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Without any success, but it works perfectly with the exact same code for UINavigationBar+Image.

the drawRect method is not getting called for UIToolbar, why is that?

Comment: I Know that using a Category to overwrite a method is wildly used in samples. However, Apples documentation states clearly, that you should Not do that and suggests to use subclassing instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

> For UIToolBar, if you’re using it within a UINavigationController, you’ll want to also override drawLayer:inContext:, as this appears to be used instead of drawRect: when used within a navigation controller, for some weird reason.

Source: http://atastypixel.com/blog/making-uitoolbar-and-uinavigationbars-background-totally-transparent/

So I implemented `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` instead:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CALayer *imgLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [imgLayer setContents:(id)[[UIImage imageNamed: @"toolbar.png"] CGImage]];
    [imgLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [imgLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2,self.bounds.size.height/2)];
    [layer insertSublayer:imgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Again, I want to emphasize, that, according to Apple, using categories to overwrite methods is wrong. It is unlikely, but your code a) might crash on future platforms/with future SDKs and b) could theoretically be rejected from the AppStore. You should read the guidelines for categories, it sais: 'Although the language currently allows you to use a category to override methods the class inherits, or even methods declared in the class interface, you are strongly discouraged from using this functionality. A category is not a substitute for a subclass.'

Comment: In the end i did subclassed it instead, because i use 3 different kinds of toolbars, image background, solid color background and default background. but, my question was really about how to get categories to work for the toolbar, not if it was a good idea to do it or not.